# I need to select two words without repeat them (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, select

I have a array list and I want to select two words from this list without repeat they. But I tried many stuff and nothing worked. There is the current code:

```
$randomq2[] = "one";
$randomq2[] = "two";
$randomq2[] = "three";


srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$getrando1 = rand(0,count($randomq2)-1);
$getrando2 = rand(0,count($randomq2)-1);


$wordone = $getrando1[$conco1];
$wordtwo = $getrando2[$conco2];
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I first get all unique elements from `$randomq2` with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Then I simply [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and at the end I just extract 2 elements from the start with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php))

```
<?php

    $randomq2 = array_unique($randomq2);
    shuffle($randomq2);
    $random = array_slice($randomq2, 0, 2);

    print_r($random);

?>
```

Comment: Worked too, and thank you for explain how it works :P

Comment: I believe that he need only the shuffle, because the problems with the code that he write can get the same array key two times, with shuffle this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can go following way:

```
$getrando1 = rand(0,count($randomq2)-1);
$getrando2 = rand(0,count($randomq2)-1);
while ($getrando2 == $getrando1)
    $getrando2 = rand(0,count($randomq2)-1);
```

also - I'd suggest you to use mt_rand instead of simple rand

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :D (i tried If before lmao now I understand)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question very well

but try this

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red");
print_r(array_unique($a));
?>
```

this will remove duplicated values in the array